# VASP DFT+U on Ti d orbital, why d orbitals are not affected but s and p orbitals are pushed lower?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

I'm using DFT+*U* implemented in VASP to calculate the electronic density of states of anatase TiO2.

In order to more accurately reproduce the experimental bandgap of anatase TiO2 (as compared to standard PBE functional), a *U* value of 4 eV was applied to the Ti *d* orbital by adding the settings below to a standard INCAR file (the first atomic species in POSCAR is Ti, and the second one is O)

```
# DFT+U Calculation
 LDAU   = TRUE
 LDATYPE=  2
 LDAUL  =  2 -1
 LDAUU  =  4 0
 LDAUJ  =  0 0
 LMAXMIX=  4
```

However, the as obtained DFT+*U* results seems to be incorrect. From the density of states as shown in the figure,

[image: dos]

rather than the Ti *d* orbital on which the *U* value is applied, it is the Ti *s* and *p* orbitals that are pushed to lower energy values. **More confusingly, the energy values of Ti *d* bonding orbitals barely changes, while the anti-bonding Ti *d* orbitals are shifted to higher energy values.**

Why this happens?

Comment: What is the zero for energy in the above plots? Is it consistent?

Comment: @IanBush I didn't do any processing on energies, they are directly read from OUTCAR files, I think it is consistent.

Comment: @IanBush Hi Ian, I have added more details in the original post, I'm really confused by the results, I would appreciate any helpful tips :)

Comment: I don't do VASP, or plane waves at all really, but from a local basis view point given Ti in TiO2 is in the +4 oxidation state and so is in principle d0 I'm not surprised that the bonding states don't shift much -  there just aren't many electrons in such states to repel each other, so the Hubbard U will make little difference.

Comment: @IanBush Thank you!

Comment: Before you get too excited I'd wait for somebody woe really knows there stuff to answer - these are comments as I'm not quite confident enugh to give them as answers

Comment: @IanBush I know :)

Comment: Following up on the comments of @IanBush, remember that a Hubbard U pushes unoccupied states *up* in energy by 0.5 U in the Hubbard limit, and occupied states *down* in energy by the same amount. Conventional chemical wisdom holds that this system has *no* occupied Ti d-states; in your actual calculation, the s-, p- and d-states are probably hybridised, and both the hybridisation and energy of the d- component will be affected by the Hubbard U.